# How can I intercept between request and response to load some resource(custom.html) on client side(browser)

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Example : Launching basic authentication popup scenario -> For a request to page(index.html) response is send with header -> WWW-Authenticate with status code 401. We can see that popup opens but request is in pending state.

Is there something similar we can do to intercept between request and response and load some other resource on client side.

[Basic Authentication Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyhrq.png)

Comment: Hi banti, you should add a lot more information and clearly state what you are trying to do and what you tried.

Comment: Edited. Request made -> from server we send the response 401, WWW-Authenticate ->pop up launches on browser, the request still does not gets completed -> username password entered correct, request completes with required response. Can we do similar thing but instead of basic authentication popup, load some other resource and original request is on hold